# Plot through the loop with separate color

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a data frame like this:

```
clusters = pd.concat(l,keys=range(len(l)))

clusters = 

            latitude    longitude
0   872     11.1248     2.5902
    873     11.1246     2.5908
    874     11.1230     2.5944
    875     11.1228     2.5943
    876     11.1157     2.5903
    ...     ...     ...     ...
3    76     11.1610     2.7873
   1226     11.1024     2.7498
   1227     11.1027     2.7500
   1228     11.1072     2.7568
   1229     11.1076     2.7563
```

Where 0,1,2,3 (total 4 clusters) shows my clusters.

I want to plot all clusters in a one loop (with a loop maybe) in the following way:

- plot cluster `0` in red and clusters `1,2,3` in grey
- plot cluster `1` in red and clusters `0,2,3` in grey
- plot cluster `2` in red and clusters `1,0,3` in grey
- plot cluster `3` in red and clusters `1,2,0` in grey

Something like

[image: this]

## MY TRY:

```
x_test = ready_couples.loc[0].longitude
y_test = ready_couples.loc[0].latitude

x_all = ready_couples.longitude
y_all = ready_couples.latitude

plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')
my_dpi=96
plt.figure(figsize=(480/my_dpi, 480/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi)

for k in ready_couples:
    plt.scatter(x_all, y_all, marker='.', color='grey', linewidth=1, alpha=0.4)
    plt.scatter(x_test, y_test, marker='.', color='orange', linewidth=4, alpha=0.7)
```

Comment: what have you tryed?

Comment: @Hans check the question. I have edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

clusters = pd.DataFrame({
    'mi': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
    'i': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'latitude': [1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5],
    'longitude': [1, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5]
})
# you can reset index if needed
# clusters = clusters.reset_index()
clusters = clusters.set_index(['mi'])
plt.plot(clusters.loc[index_in_red,'latitude'], clusters.loc[index_in_red,'longitude'], 'r')
plt.plot(clusters.loc[clusters.index != index_in_red,'latitude'], clusters.loc[clusters.index != index_in_red,'longitude'], 'grey')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Seems like what I have done. I want a loop doing it for the all clusters

Comment: you can put plotting code in this loop: `for index_in_red in clusters.index.unique():`

Comment: I am getting more than 3000 same plots

Comment: Do you have multiindex or simple index?

Comment: I was about to add this comment. In your case value of `mi` in every row, but in my case I have only once. And I do not have a name of this indexes like `mi` in your case

Comment: You can reset multiindex and set index again on one column that you need for visualization

Comment: I asked a question which is the related to your answer. If you are interested, ya can check :)